# Windows 10 PC with multiple network adapters and connections

Tags: windows, networking, ssh

I have a windows 10 PC with two network adapters.
One network adapter connects PC to lab LAN.
The other network adapter connects PC to a storage box, that exports a logical volume and on PC we see it as P:.
My problem is that, if I ssh into this PC from other computers in lab, I don't see the P:\ drive.
I need to see the P:\ that is on other network and be able to access it normally.
What do I need to do?
Thanks,

Comment: Try mapping from other computers to this computer by IP address. You probably have different subnets (PC, Storage Box, 2 NICs).

Comment: Try enabling smb1.0 on the windows machine and mount the drive that way. It's less secure but as long as your lan is protected by firewall it should be all good

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities here:

1. You have your storage connected as block device. Then it should appear as regular hard drive. You should be able to share it as regular disk via samba share.
2. You have samba (windows) share network drive mapped to your PC. In this case you can not share it further (actually there is a [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6850179/sharing-a-windows-mapped-drive), but it might not work on 10).
   Solution here is to add direct routes to network storage.